# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, requests, ssl, https, certificate

Дорогие программисты из StackOverflow, надеюсь кто-либо из вас может мне помочь.

Вот что произошло: У меня скрипт питона, который выполняет запросы на веб-сервис с помощью библиотеки requests. Соединение с Веб-сервисом открывается под протоколом HTTPS, и до буквально пару часов назад все работало нормально. 
После отключения/подключения сервера в другом зале, скрипт перестал работать, выдается теперь сбой:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

Для сведения, код с использованием функцией `requests.post`:

```
import requests

r=requests.post(url="https://moilokalnyserver.moidomen/put/do/metoda",
                data="User=MoiPolzovatel&Password=MoiParol", 
                headers={'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                verify=True)
```

Полный выход:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

Вопрос о том, какая может быть причина, ведь запросы нормально отлично работали и вдруг сбой?
Благодарю за любое предложение на решение.

**Актуализация**

Используя Postman и обычный запрос через браузера, появляется сбой 500. Однако при открытии информации по сертификату, она действительна.

Посмотрел решения, предложенные на ответах [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) на английском сайте StackOverflow, но учитывая что раньше все работало нормально, думаю что есть еще какая-то проблема, связанная с перезагрузкой сервера.

Comment: На вебсервисе сертификат от let’s encrypt? Перестало работать утром 1-го октября?

Comment: Если да и да - то вы наткнулись на истечение одного из корневых сертификатов, и отсутствие нового корневего в доверенных - https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/. Решается обновлением клиентской стороны, в вашем случае скорее всего питона до более свежего, с OpenSSL 1.1.0

Comment: Скорее всего да letsencrypt, я обратился к айти, чтобы узнавать. Перестало работать 30 сентября вечером.

Answer (score 1):

"SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" - бот пытается связаться с сайтом, но видит у него неизвестный сертификат. Нужно вручную загрузить этот сертификат в доверенные:

1. На сайте нажать на замок (рядом с url) --> найти действительный сертификат --> во вкладке дополнительно экспортировать его в формате ".crt"
2. Oткрыть "MMC" через пуск. Далее файл --> добавить оснастку --> сертификаты --> добавить --> моей учётной (затем также добавить для локального пк) --> откройте через корень консоли сертификаты - локальный пк --> действие --> все задачи --> далее и обзор --> найдите скачанный в п.1 сертификат --> готово!

Answer (score 0):

Так, я успел временно обойти такой сбой, путем отключения верификации сертификата `verify=False`.

Внизу отображается полная строка:

```
r=requests.post(url="https://moilokalnyserver.moidomen/put/do/metoda",
                data="User=MoiPolzovatel&Password=MoiParol", 
                headers={'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                verify=False)
```

В первую минуту думал, что не помогло, потому что появляется предупреждение:

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
> "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 852
> InsecureRequestWarning) InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly
> advised. See:
> https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

На такое предупреждение стоит обращать внимание в связи с рисками безопасности, т.е. такое является временным решением. Сама проблема остается. Чтобы отключить предупреждения, нужно добавить следующую строку, прежде чем отправить запрос HTTPS:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```