# проверка большого списка асинхронно

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Есть вот такой огромный список. делаем все через `asyncio`. На ПК работает отлично, но как только я упаковываю все в apk формат и запускаю на смартфоне, результат всевремя возвращается `false`, вконце. Хотя список при этом, что на пк, что на смартфоне одинаковый.
Я уже и бил список на части, по 100 - не помогло.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def prox(url):
    async def fetch(url, headers, Proxytype, proxsss, response):
        try:
            async with response.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=f'{Proxytype}://{proxsss}', timeout=15) as respon:
                try:
                    return respon.status
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return None
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
    async def wait_first_completed(futures):
        while True:
            if not futures:
                return None
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(futures, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            for item in done:
                result = item.result()
                if result is not None:
                    for pending_task in pending:
                        pending_task.cancel()
                    return  result

            futures = pending

    Proxytypes = ['http', 'https']
    listProx1 = []
    listProx2 = []
    for Proxytype in Proxytypes:
        headers = {'User-Agent': f'{UserAgent().random}', }
        try:
            responseS = requests.get(f'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol={Proxytype}&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all',
                                    headers=headers, timeout=30)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(responseS.text, 'html.parser')
        except:
            continue
        soup = str(soup.encode('utf-8'))
        soup = soup.replace("b'", '')
        soup = soup.replace("'", '')
        soup = soup.split('\\r\\n')
        soup = [x for x in soup if x]
        for xx in soup:
            if Proxytype == Proxytypes[0]:
                listProx1.append(xx)
            else:
                listProx2.append(xx)
        responseS.close()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as response:
        futures = []
        for proxsss in listProx1:
            futures.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(url, headers, Proxytypes[0], proxsss, response)))
        result = await wait_first_completed(futures)
        if result == 200:
            return (proxsss, Proxytype[0])

        futures = []
        for proxsss in listProx2:
            futures.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch(url, headers, Proxytypes[1], proxsss, response)))
        result = await wait_first_completed(futures)
        if result == 200:
            return (proxsss, Proxytype[1])

    return ('false', 'false')

proxs, protocol = asyncio.run(prox('https://www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua'))
print(f'{protocol}, {proxs}')
```

В логах работы приложения ошибок нет. При этом этот же список без `asyncio`, то есть долго и мучетельно подряд все перебирает пока не наткнется на рабочий, работает нормально и находит.

**UPD:** Добавил чтобы выводило в лог ошибки при попытки подключения.
Весь лог работы кода в Android:

```
12-01 14:15:32.276 28010 28041 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (1)] api.proxyscrape.com:443
12-01 14:15:34.439 28010 28041 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [https          ]//api.proxyscrape.com:443 "GET /v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=http&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all HTTP/1.1" 200 5875
12-01 14:15:34.516 28010 28041 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (1)] api.proxyscrape.com:443
12-01 14:15:35.734 28010 28041 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [https          ]//api.proxyscrape.com:443 "GET /v2/?request=displayproxies&protocol=https&timeout=10000&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all HTTP/1.1" 200 12309
12-01 14:15:37.558 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 119.13.111.169:8291 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('119.13.111.169', 8291)]
12-01 14:15:38.631 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Expected HTTP/', url=URL('http://65.20.235.40:8080')
12-01 14:15:38.636 28010 28041 I python  : Server disconnected
12-01 14:15:38.660 28010 28041 I python  : 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('http://157.25.92.74:3128')
12-01 14:15:38.664 28010 28041 I python  : 500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('http://158.69.212.254:80')
12-01 14:15:38.756 28010 28041 I python  : Server disconnected
12-01 14:15:38.821 28010 28041 I python  : Server disconnected
12-01 14:15:38.849 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Expected HTTP/', url=URL('http://193.239.56.84:8081')
12-01 14:15:38.939 28010 28041 I python  : 500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('http://195.114.209.50:80')
12-01 14:15:38.998 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad request', url=URL('http://198.58.106.30:8086')
12-01 14:15:39.043 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('http://47.56.110.204:8989')
12-01 14:15:39.075 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('http://39.165.0.137:9002')
12-01 14:15:39.159 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Expected HTTP/', url=URL('http://103.216.49.178:8080')
12-01 14:15:39.233 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('http://159.203.61.169:3128')
12-01 14:15:39.267 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('http://139.59.1.14:3128')
12-01 14:15:39.781 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('http://121.183.80.210:80')
12-01 14:15:39.791 28010 28041 I python  : 400, message='Bad Request', url=URL('http://47.88.3.19:8080')
12-01 14:15:39.866 28010 28041 I python  : [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
12-01 14:15:39.871 28010 28041 I python  : [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
12-01 14:15:39.896 28010 28041 I python  : 503, message='Too many open connections', url=URL('http://222.102.90.167:7339')
12-01 14:15:39.926 28010 28041 I python  : 500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('http://153.19.91.77:80')
12-01 14:15:40.794 28010 28041 I python  : 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('http://197.243.20.178:80')
12-01 14:15:40.801 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:40.817 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:40.824 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 186.4.147.10:8080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('186.4.147.10', 8080)]
12-01 14:15:40.910 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 163.53.82.238:32650 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('163.53.82.238', 32650)]
12-01 14:15:41.640 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 202.154.18.9:8080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('202.154.18.9', 8080)]
12-01 14:15:42.116 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:42.144 28010 28041 I python  : 500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('http://74.48.220.109:80')
12-01 14:15:42.190 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:42.577 28010 28041 I python  : 502, message='Bad Gateway', url=URL('http://176.31.197.145:8080')
12-01 14:15:43.578 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:44.338 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:44.465 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:44.523 28010 28041 I python  : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_extra_info'
12-01 14:15:44.708 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 103.167.71.38:8080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('103.167.71.38', 8080)]
12-01 14:15:44.850 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:45.235 28010 28041 I python  : Server disconnected
12-01 14:15:45.311 28010 28041 I python  : Server disconnected
12-01 14:15:45.486 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:47.105 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 179.0.43.45:999 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('179.0.43.45', 999)]
12-01 14:15:47.999 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:48.805 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:49.183 28010 28041 I python  : 500, message='Internal Server Error', url=URL('http://195.15.215.146:80')
12-01 14:15:49.322 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 31.210.172.11:3128 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('31.210.172.11', 3128)]
12-01 14:15:50.463 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:50.580 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host www.telefonnyjdovidnyk.com.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:50.651 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 174.138.184.82:38661 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('174.138.184.82', 38661)]
12-01 14:15:50.659 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 45.190.170.254:999 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('45.190.170.254', 999)]
12-01 14:15:50.798 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 41.65.236.43:1981 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('41.65.236.43', 1981)]
12-01 14:15:51.168 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:15:51.341 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:15:52.163 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:15:52.376 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:15:55.117 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 119.13.111.169:55443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('119.13.111.169', 55443)]
12-01 14:15:55.131 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 119.13.111.169:8291 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('119.13.111.169', 8291)]
12-01 14:15:55.537 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 46.35.9.110:80 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:55.579 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 194.53.158.57:53281 ssl:default [Connection reset by peer]
12-01 14:15:55.612 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 43.251.132.133:8080 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:56.056 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 45.11.95.165:5211 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:56.327 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 59.26.254.243:8193 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:56.414 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 132.148.82.125:45605 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('132.148.82.125', 45605)]
12-01 14:15:56.511 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 180.87.170.21:1080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('180.87.170.21', 1080)]
12-01 14:15:56.577 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 192.111.139.165:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:56.727 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 192.111.130.5:17002 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:56.788 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 65.20.235.40:8080 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:56.835 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 142.54.231.38:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:56.871 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 67.43.236.20:22909 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:57.166 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 192.252.214.20:15864 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.777 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 65.20.235.217:8080 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:57.786 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 72.195.34.41:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.801 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 184.178.172.11:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.841 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 68.71.247.130:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.851 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 72.195.114.184:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.858 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 72.206.181.97:64943 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.865 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 74.119.144.60:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.873 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 192.252.208.70:14282 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:57.881 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 103.118.46.61:8080 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:57.892 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 159.65.221.25:80 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:58.042 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 98.188.47.132:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.093 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 66.29.154.103:3128 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('66.29.154.103', 3128)]
12-01 14:15:58.101 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 64.225.4.17:10007 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.109 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 68.183.144.115:10000 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.116 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 177.87.28.247:4153 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.123 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 107.181.161.81:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.131 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 184.178.172.23:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.141 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 83.243.92.154:8080 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:58.150 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 178.54.21.203:8081 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:58.163 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 12.7.109.3:56981 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.179 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 79.101.106.74:33608 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.296 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 67.43.236.20:31487 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:58.301 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 8.213.128.6:3129 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:58.398 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 198.8.94.170:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.443 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 119.13.103.211:4006 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:58.667 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 120.55.49.231:8989 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('120.55.49.231', 8989)]
12-01 14:15:58.863 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 72.217.216.239:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.881 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 113.161.131.43:80 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.926 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 98.181.137.80:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:15:58.936 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 119.13.111.169:3128 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:15:58.979 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 204.188.210.195:4128 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:58.982 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 117.158.146.215:9091 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:15:59.533 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 207.244.254.27:1195 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:00.610 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 92.255.190.64:4153 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:01.042 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 68.183.16.227:50589 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:01.458 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 177.66.101.223:8024 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('177.66.101.223', 8024)]
12-01 14:16:01.508 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 49.50.69.240:48960 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:01.515 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 110.34.3.229:3128 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:01.524 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 181.212.58.68:80 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:01.534 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 68.1.210.189:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:01.545 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 188.87.137.45:3128 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:01.656 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 47.254.47.61:8081 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:16:01.705 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 173.249.33.122:49382 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:02.289 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 139.129.231.228:3000 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('139.129.231.228', 3000)]
12-01 14:16:02.305 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 198.57.229.185:45190 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('198.57.229.185', 45190)]
12-01 14:16:02.318 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 164.92.92.85:41182 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('164.92.92.85', 41182)]
12-01 14:16:02.332 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 104.45.128.122:80 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:02.379 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 92.205.61.38:50752 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('92.205.61.38', 50752)]
12-01 14:16:02.391 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 101.200.187.233:4145 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('101.200.187.233', 4145)]
12-01 14:16:02.398 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 45.118.218.196:35010 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('45.118.218.196', 35010)]
12-01 14:16:02.405 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 120.236.67.189:9002 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('120.236.67.189', 9002)]
12-01 14:16:02.412 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 101.96.123.21:1080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('101.96.123.21', 1080)]
12-01 14:16:02.419 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 112.51.96.118:9091 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('112.51.96.118', 9091)]
12-01 14:16:02.448 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 188.166.17.18:8881 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:02.516 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 34.154.161.152:80 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('34.154.161.152', 80)]
12-01 14:16:02.845 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 120.55.49.231:8002 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('120.55.49.231', 8002)]
12-01 14:16:02.862 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 120.55.49.231:8009 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('120.55.49.231', 8009)]
12-01 14:16:03.190 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 119.13.111.169:55443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('119.13.111.169', 55443)]
12-01 14:16:03.344 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 64.225.8.203:10001 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('64.225.8.203', 10001)]
12-01 14:16:03.401 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 109.254.81.159:9090 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:03.444 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 88.99.249.96:8286 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:03.512 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 170.254.244.107:35010 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('170.254.244.107', 35010)]
12-01 14:16:03.920 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 45.190.170.254:999 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('45.190.170.254', 999)]
12-01 14:16:04.267 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 184.181.217.213:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:04.633 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 142.54.235.9:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:04.735 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 68.71.254.6:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:04.752 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 184.178.172.26:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:05.011 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 42.248.122.147:1080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('42.248.122.147', 1080)]
12-01 14:16:05.023 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 164.40.194.76:8080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('164.40.194.76', 8080)]
12-01 14:16:05.253 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 45.235.46.94:8080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('45.235.46.94', 8080)]
12-01 14:16:05.379 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 141.101.123.55:80 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:05.895 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 62.171.134.234:37898 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('62.171.134.234', 37898)]
12-01 14:16:05.944 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 77.75.120.142:4128 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('77.75.120.142', 4128)]
12-01 14:16:05.953 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 47.109.57.93:8999 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('47.109.57.93', 8999)]
12-01 14:16:05.961 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 80.106.247.145:5678 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('80.106.247.145', 5678)]
12-01 14:16:05.970 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 101.51.55.153:8080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('101.51.55.153', 8080)]
12-01 14:16:06.117 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 184.178.172.18:15280 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:06.129 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 179.49.117.98:888 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('179.49.117.98', 888)]
12-01 14:16:06.175 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 74.252.14.169:59420 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('74.252.14.169', 59420)]
12-01 14:16:06.183 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 159.224.243.185:61303 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('159.224.243.185', 61303)]
12-01 14:16:06.191 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 194.233.78.142:35314 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('194.233.78.142', 35314)]
12-01 14:16:06.199 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 113.195.207.249:9091 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('113.195.207.249', 9091)]
12-01 14:16:06.206 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 212.73.75.60:4337 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('212.73.75.60', 4337)]
12-01 14:16:06.213 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 188.124.230.43:17662 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('188.124.230.43', 17662)]
12-01 14:16:06.220 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 58.22.60.174:1080 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('58.22.60.174', 1080)]
12-01 14:16:06.224 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 95.31.5.29:54651 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('95.31.5.29', 54651)]
12-01 14:16:06.228 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 154.66.109.41:10081 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('154.66.109.41', 10081)]
12-01 14:16:06.243 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 120.79.16.132:8999 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('120.79.16.132', 8999)]
12-01 14:16:06.270 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 157.245.46.100:31280 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')]
12-01 14:16:06.487 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 217.182.170.224:80 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:07.401 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 27.109.202.74:80 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:08.040 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 5.161.103.41:88 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:08.057 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 199.102.104.70:4145 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:08.066 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 117.54.114.99:80 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:08.078 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 3.20.32.159:80 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
12-01 14:16:08.116 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 101.36.120.133:30010 ssl:default [None]
12-01 14:16:08.170 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:08.331 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:08.829 28010 28041 I python  : Cannot connect to host 221.230.216.54:7788 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('221.230.216.54', 7788)]
12-01 14:16:09.202 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.400 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.402 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.408 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.409 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.418 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.419 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.429 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.430 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.437 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.438 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.440 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.441 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.443 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.444 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.446 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.447 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.453 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.453 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.456 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.456 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.459 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.459 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.462 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.463 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.465 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.466 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.468 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.469 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:09.470 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:10.148 28010 28041 I python  : 
12-01 14:16:10.159 28010 28041 I python  : 
false, false
```

видно в начале что получено почти 17000 прокси и он не проверил все, а вернул `false` и на рабочий тоже не натыкался.

Comment: Вообще-то многопоточночть это не тема для формата вопрос/ответ. Но вообще оказывается есть вопрос аналогичный вашему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python?rq=1 и решение там тоже есть.

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko к сожалению, то совсем просто про отдельний поток для проверки подряд всех прокси, в котором я лишь подметил выход из него. Мне же нужно проверить асинхронно, параллельно 2000 почти прокси, и при этом не делать дальше код пока либо не вернется рабочий или не проверятся все. Я же не могу для каждого асинхрон функции, в цикле, поставить join(), как то не правильно.

Comment: Если через асинхронность (синтаксис async/await), то нужно менять requests на асинхронные библиотеки (aiohttp или httpx), запускать все через asyncio.wait с параметром `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`

Comment: @insolor о, не знал о таком для reqiests, буду изучать

Comment: @insolor нашел ваш ответ же, только со списком сайтов, все тоже проделал и все ок работает. Благодарю за наводку.

Comment: А, [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1516940/1365) видимо, действительно похожая задача

Comment: @insolor да, он. Возникла не понятная сложность. Я отредактировал тему, та бы не делать дубликаты. Может сможете помочь.

Comment: Ну тут имеет смысл логирование ошибок добавить в except, примерно так же как в моем ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1516940/1365. Полный игнор ошибок лучше не делать, вы так не узнаете из-за чего что-то то пошло не так.

Comment: Два раза в try-except не обязательно оборачивать, можно внешний оставить, и в нем уже логирование добавить.

Comment: Еще не исключено, что на предыдущем этапе что-то пошло не так, и listProx1 и listProx2 оказались пустыми.

Comment: @insolor списки не пустые, выводил их значение в лог. Сейчас сделаю вывод ошибок и посмотрю, но скорей всего там будет просто не возможность коннекта к сайту через указаные прокси, если они не рабочими окажутся или сайт не потдерживает их порт. Я тут еще вычитал про:```from async_gui.engine import Task, MultiProcessTask
from async_gui.toolkits.kivy import KivyEngine```, но возможно это устаревшее и для android `asyncio` работае ок

Comment: А, у вас еще и на киви. Ну по идее это не должно мешать проверке, просто интерфейс фризиться должен. async_gui - это именно для того чтобы можно было асинхронность в gui приложениях использовать (чтобы интерфейс не фризился).

Comment: P.S. хотя похоже async_gui это вообще не про async/await, судя по тому что он Python 2.7 поддерживает

Comment: @insolor понял про ту библиотеку. Я отредактировал тему и добавил лог

Comment: Попробовал кучу других прокси, со всеми так. не понимаю

Comment: @insolor я так понимаю смартфон просто не выдерживает столько запросов одновременно, асинхронно. Подряд еще как-то и то это выглядит ужасно на смартфоне в логе, когда 10000 запросов на проверку прокси. Я так понимаю выход это иметь конкретные несколько прокси рабочих и с открытыми всеми портами или же делать запросы без прокси.

Comment: Еще смотря на лог думаю попробовать это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333600/ssl-certificate-verify-failed или это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, для тех у кого такая же проблема будет. Да, все дело в ошибках:

```
Cannot connect to host 157.245.46.100:31280 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')]
Cannot connect to host 65.20.235.40:8080 ssl:default [[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)]
```

Это означает, что протокол который вы используете в прокси, не подходит ему. Например прокси = `http://65.20.235.40:8080`, но у Вас выкидывает ошибки указаные выше. Значит Вам следует сменить прокси на = `https://65.20.235.40:8080` и все заработает. И наоборот ситуация та же.

возможно не у всех сработает поэтом временное решение это применить опцию в запросе `ssl=False`, а для `requests` вместо `ssl` написать `verify`. Пробовал вместо `False` указать путь к сертификату, но всеравно ошибка, сильно не вникал, но там походу проблема в написании самого сертификата, что-то не указано или не верно указано.